# Difference between https and http post method

Tags: http, post, https, server

https retrieves data from the server in secure way, http or https post method as I know sends data encoded for reassuring sensitive information. **If both https and post method secures data what is the difference**

Answer (score 2):

HTTP POST request will be sent unencrypted and any middle man in the communication can see the plain text

However with HTTPS all the data is encrypted and only the server can decrypt it to see the data that's coming

You maybe misunderstanding that encoding is not encryption by the way.

Comment: yeah I was confused about encoding and encryption. Can you answer me one more thing? the purpose of encoding is to compress data right? cause post method data could be big compared

Comment: Yes Content-Encoding header is used to compress data like gzip for example but that does not relate here in post request encoding usually refers to changing the data to some structure so the server can reassemble the information. Post request encoding includes JSON,  application/x-www-form-urlencoded, etc...